# how to convert .to files to a popular audio format

Tags: file-extension, file-conversion, audio-conversion

I have received an audio file with extension `.To` from a friend. I have found a player for this file type, but I want to convert it to a popular audio format in order to play it in my other gadgets. I googled and found nothing! Is there anyone to help me out in this?

Comment: What is the name of the player you've found and worked?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a PSP Audio File. If that is the case, it can be converted with Audioro PSP Converter (free).
If not, better you attach it so we can identify it.